# How can I open a file inside of an exe inside of my c++ app

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

Question is I have this button that when clicked I would like it open a file for me inside of a specific executable.

I am a tad rusty on c++ and this is a legacy application using c++ 6.0
built on windows xp.....So any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is my code cpp

```
void CJunkView::OnCadkeyButton() 

  {
   CString fileToOpen = "C:\\Documents and Settings\\Administrator\\Desktop\\x.prt";
   CString exePath = "C:\\CK19\\Ckwin.exe";
   system ("start (exePath), (fileToOpen)");
  }
```

When I click this button it returns this Windows cannot find 'exePath,'.Make sure you typed the name correctly and then try again.

Comment: Nothing here seems to indicate any usage of C++/CLI code (just looks like C++ with MFC).

Comment: The part you're missing, and that no-one's spelled out is that **that's not how string interpolation works in C or C++**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to build a string that contains the entire system call and the pass the buffer of that string to `system()`

Edit:

In response to the comment by [IInspectable](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1889329/iinspectable) we could just use the implicit conversion operator [`operator LPCTSTR()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa300569(v=vs.60).aspx)

```
void CJunkView::OnCadkeyButton() 
{
   CString fileToOpen = "C:\\Documents and settings\\Administrator\\Desktop\\x.prt";
   CString exePath = "C:\\CK19\\Ckwin.exe";
   CString cmd = "start " + exePath + ", " + fileToOpen;
   system (cmd);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you help I just tired your suggestion and it gave me this error. GetBuffer' : function does not take 0 parameters @NathanOliver

Comment: @Snowman288 sorry for that.  Forgot that `GetBUffer()` needs a size for it.  I am so used to using `std::string` where this is not needed.

Comment: Thanks for that for some reason I get this error now --> Windows cannot find 'C:\CK19\Ckwin.exe,'. make sure you typed the name correctly and then try again. @NathanOliver

Comment: @Snowman288 `"C:\\CK19\\Ckwin.exe"` might need to be `"\"C:\\CK19\\Ckwin.exe\""`

Comment: [CString::GetBuffer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kt26tkzx.aspx) returns a modifiable buffer, and necessitates a call to [CString::ReleaseBuffer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/32x198c7.aspx), when you're done. If you only need a const pointer to the internal buffer, simply use the implicit conversion operator: `system(cmd);`. Then again, why would you even consider launching the command interpreter, when you have [ShellExecuteEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762154.aspx) and friends.

Comment: @IInspectable thanks for that.  I have added it into the answer.

Comment: The implementation that needlessly retrieves a modifiable pointer to the `CString` contents doesn't add anything useful. It is unnecessarily complex, wastes clock cycles for no reason, and is less readable. Completely deleting it improves your answer.